# Workflow - Copy lookup field to another field without getting the lookup id infront

Tags: workflow, lookup-column, workflow-lookup

I've got a workflow that I want to combine a lookup field and a regular field into another field. This because both list can contain the same company and I want to group the list based on company name.

But when I try to copy a lookup field I get the ID infront of the name.

Ex. (lookupfield) Coca Cola turns into 114;#Coca Cola when I copy to another field

How do I remove the lookup id (114;#) in front of the Coca cola. Is there a way to use regex in the workflow?

The id can be 1-2-3-4-5 digits .. so it does not have the same length :(

Comment: you build your workflow in VS or SPD??

Comment: @MiladFrancis SPD

Comment: Can i see how you built your workflow,